# How to install PHPMailer on Win7

Tags: php

I want to setup PHPMailer; however, I cannot find any satisfactory documentation for that. I 've already installed Apache 2.2 in my machine and PHP 5.3.10. Also, I 've downloaded PHPMailer. Now, I want to test PHPMailer through my PC(localhost) without uploading to online web server.Is it possible?

Do I have to copy files inside Apache/htdocs folder or inside PHP folder? Do I have to make any changes to  php.ini? What else is necessary? Do I need to setup an SMTP server locally (if yes how)?

Thank you

P.S. I am trying PHPMailer since I could not send mail via PHP function mail()

Comment: You can set it up using an external SMTP server as well – you just have to provide the necessary data as described in the readme file: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: You didn't search in google right? http://myfreeopensource.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/how-to-install-and-configure-apachephpmysqlphpmyadminphpmailer-on-windows/